# Unsigned shift right in C# Using Java semantics for negative numbers

Tags: c#, java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to port Java code to C# and I'm running into odd bugs related to the unsigned shift right operator >>> normally the code:

```
long l = (long) ((ulong) number) >> 2;
```

Would be the equivalent of Java's:

```
long l = number >>> 2;
```

However for the case of `-2147483648L` which you might recognized as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` this returns a different number than it would in Java since the cast to `ulong` changes the semantics of the number hence I get a different result.

How would something like this be possible in C#?

I'd like to preserve the code semantics as much as possible since its a pretty complex body of code.

Comment: Could it be the placement of your parenthesis (thus producing a different/unexpected order of operations)? For example, shifting your number with your example code of `(long) ((ulong) number) >> 2` yields `-536870912` whereas wrapping the `ulong` conversion (and shifting) with parenthesis `(long) (((ulong) number) >> 2)` yields `4611686017890516992`. EDIT: I think your first example converts `number` to `ulong`, then back to `long` before shifting, whereas my expression converts to `ulong`, shifts, then converts back to `long`.

Comment: Damn I feel stupid, looking for a complex answer for something this trivial!  Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your expression is incorrect when considering C#'s order precedence. Your code I believe is converting your `long` to `ulong`, then back to `long`, *then* shifting. I'm assuming your intent was to perform the shift on the `ulong`.

From the [C# Specification §7.2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), Unary (or in your case, the casting operation) takes precedence over the shifting. Thus your code:

```
long l = (long) ((ulong) number) >> 2;
```

would be interpreted as:

```
ulong ulongNumber = (ulong)number;
long longNumber = (long)ulongNumber;
long shiftedlongNumber = longNumber >> 2;
```

Given `number` as `-2147483648L`, this yields `536870912`.

By wrapping the conversion and shifting in parenthesis:

```
long l = (long) (((ulong) number) >> 2);
```

Produces logic that could be rewritten as:

```
ulong ulongNumber = (ulong)number;
ulong shiftedulongNumber = ulongNumber >> 2;
long longShiftedNumber = (long)shiftedulongNumber;
```

Which given `number` as `-2147483648L`, this yields `4611686017890516992`.

---

EDIT: Note that given those ordering rules, there's an extra set of parenthesis in my answer that aren't necessary. The correct expression could be written as:

```
long l = (long) ((ulong) number >> 2);
```